# User authentication- Security risk passing session cookie over HTTP?

Tags: php, http, session, https, session-cookies

I have a "Client Center" on my website which is only accessible via HTTPS. I'm currently using a single session cookie to track PHP session variables such as User_Authenticated, Client_ID, etc once they log in.

I want to change the links on my navigation bar from "Login" to "Logout | Client Center" once they have logged in. This is easy enough, but most of my website has absolute links that point to HTTP instead of HTTPS. I could make all of my links relative and that way hopefully keep them on HTTPS once they've logged in, but my site is graphics-intensive and I can't guarantee that they'll stay on HTTPS (if, for instance, they type http://mysite.com on their browser after logging in).

My question is as follows:

1) Is there a risk in passing this cookie over HTTP? I hear that it can be intercepted and spoofed. That would be bad!

2) Can I use two cookies, one which is a secure_only cookie which contains their credentials, and another which just lets the browser know if they're logged in or not, for the links on my navigation bar? Is it possible to use multiple sessions simultaneously like this with different cookies?

I've also heard about using a database-based session management system, but for now that is way over my head. I'm new to PHP and MySQL (this is my first site).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you using standard sessions, which store all of the actual session data on the server, leaving just an ID on the client?  In any case, anything HTTP can be sniffed, easily.

Comment: Ahh, is that how it works? That's what I'm doing (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want, using a second cookie. Then you can use the session cookie for HTTP and HTTPS pages (to get the login state), but make the authentication only with the second HTTPS-only cookie.

I wrote an [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_nomim_cookie), describing how to separate this two concerns, maintaining the session and authentication. It's a good thing to do, even if you decide to use HTTPS for the whole site.

I would think about enforcing HTTPS for the whole site though, this would make your life easier. If your site has not very high traffic, it should be no problem for todays servers.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. You're my hero! :o)

Answer (score 1):

Authentication cookies being passed over http is a bad idea.  That's the problem that firesheep brought to light, and the reason that Google, Facebook and Twitter, among others, now encourage (or require) https all the time.

If you're worried about sesion hijacking on your web site then you should be enforcing https for every page and asset that needs to be secured.  Ideally enforce https for all assets to avoid annoying borwser warnings about mixed security on the page.

Comment: So basically I need to force HTTPS for my entire site. I'm curious though, for instance, StackOverflow isn't using HTTPS and they're passing session cookies to authenticate users, right? My name is at the top of the page and I can click it to view my profile, I can make posts without having to log in, etc. Aren't they using cookies for authentication?

Comment: Yes, and StackOverflow is probably vulnerable to a firesheep-style attack.  It only really becomes an issue if you're using SO in a public wi-fi hotspot (or some other public network) and someone is capturing your network traffic.  If they can capture your session cookie, they can hijack your session.  I'm less worried about my SO session, though than, say, gmail one.

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks again for taking the time to help me with this Andrew. I most definitely appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

http://systembash.com/content/force-https-ssl-access-url-apache/

Comment: That's what I was doing initially, but I'm on shared hosting and the extra overhead was killing the performance of my site. I wouldn't mind if only authenticated users were viewing it over HTTPS, but the majority of visitors wont be members.

Comment: Why don't you separate the member only and public site, the member only with less graphics.

Comment: With a rewrite, you still send the initial request in clear before it's redirected to HTTPS. If you're not careful, you might leak the cookie there.